# Unable to integrate with Qt

Tags: ros, catkin-make, qt4

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement Grid based FAST SLAM in ROS. I have taken the source code from http://openslam.org/gridslam.html .

I have made a catkin package and put all the source code in src folder.
Now, I am trying to build that package using
$catkin_make

It is giving me the error:
qapplication.h No such file or directory.

I have qt4 installed already and have qapplication.h file at /usr/include/qt4/Qt

I have tried using .pro file and qmake but still its giving me the error.
what should I do please help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148611/unable-to-integrate-with-qt./) by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

write the following lines in your Cmake

```
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
rosbuild_add_executable(qt_test src/qt_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qt_test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

also please see this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/104666/how-to-use-qt-libraries-in-ros/#104886)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on 2014-04-05**:
but instead of
rosbuild_add_executable(qt_test src/qt_test.cpp)

add_executable(qt_test src/qt_test.cpp)  worked for me..

Thanx :)

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-04-06**:
rosbuild_add_executable for rosbuild system and add_executable for catkin. I made mistake that I thought you worked with rosbuild system...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would start by googling about using Qt in catkin. For exmaple this turns up (have not checked if it is good): https://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1